# Do I need any vaccination for Europe-USA-SouthAmerica trip?

Tags: health, ireland, colombia, miami

I am Colombian citizen currently living in Ireland. I plan to go to Miami and then to Colombia, returning using the same way.

Is there any vaccination requirement in this case?

Comment: There’s some advice here https://travelhealthpro.org.uk/country/53/colombia#Vaccine_recommendations and here https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Colombia.html

Answer (score 1):

The [World Health Organization](https://www.who.int/ith/vaccines/en/) has a comprehensive list of vaccines that should be  routinely used by travelers, some that are selectively used and the really few ones that are (might be) required: Yellow fever for a [lot of countries](https://www.who.int/ith/ITH_country_list.pdf?ua=1) and Meningococcal disease and polio (required by Saudi Arabia for pilgrims, updates are available [here](http://www.who.int/wer)).

Since the requirements for vaccination depend on the specifics parts of the country you're going to travel (and that was not mentioned in the original question), I'll add the current (as of Mai/2019) WHO recommendations for Colombia:

```
Yellow fever (2014)
Country requirement: no
Yellow fever vaccination recommendation: yes
Generally not recommended for travellers to the cities of:
- Barranquilla
- Cali
- Cartagena 
- Medellín

Not recommended for travellers whose itineraries are limited to all areas above 2300m, the department of San Andrès y Providencia and the capital city of 
Bogotá.

Malaria (2013): Malaria risk high in some municipalities of the Departments of: 
- Antioquia
- Bolivar
- Cauca
- Choco
- Cordoba
- Guajira
- Narino
- Risaralda

At a lower level, risk is also present in some municipalities of:
- Amazonas
- Caqueta
- Guaviare
- Guainia
- Meta
- Putumayo
- Vaupes
- Vichada

Chloroquineresistant P. falciparum is present.
```

For the U.S. there is no country requirement and also no recommendation from the WHO regarding yellow fever vaccination.